# How can Sun burn in space?

Tags: thermodynamics, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, sun, fusion

If there is no oxygen in space how can sun burn in space. (even though I know fire is caused by nuclear reaction inside sun)

Comment: Burning and fire are chemical processes. Nuclear reactions are not. Sun is just hot, similarly as tungsten spiral in an incandescent bulb is just hot, but is not burning.

Answer (score 1):

The nuclear reactions inside the Sun do not require oxygen. They are nuclear fusion reactions, mostly involving isotopes of hydrogen and helium. Wikipedia gives a good introduction (e.g. look up "Sun" and "solar fusion"). The phrase "hydrogen burning" is used in discussing stars, as a way of saying which nuclear fusion reaction is the dominant one. This is a technical use of the word "burning" different from its use in other contexts, such as ordinary fires on Earth which get their energy from chemical reactions involving oxygen.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct to assume that because fire cannot burn without oxygen as it isn't possible to sustain a fire in the vacuum of space. However, fire is a chemical reaction, whereas the sun "burns" fuel in a completely different way to something like a campfire. Essentially, it smashes hydrogen atoms together to form heavier helium atoms in a process known as *nuclear fusion*. You can probably imagine that these collisions cause a small release of energy, and as a result heat up the surrounding atoms. This energy, which radiates out from the sun's core eventually makes its way to the surface of the sun, and when it has no more atoms to heat up, it radiates out into space in the form of heat and light.